# Is this result on tensor products of faithful modules known?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

On the first page of [this preprint](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/faithful_OX.pdf), I give a proof (a simplification
of an argument suggested by Ken Goodearl) that if  *k*  is a field,
*A*  and  *B* are *k*-algebras (not necessarily commutative),  *M*  is a faithful
left *A*-module, and  *N*  is a faithful left *B*-module, then the left
*A* ⊗*<sub>k</sub> B*-module  *M* ⊗<sub>*k*</sub> N  is again faithful.  It is hard to believe 
this is not classical.  Does anyone know a reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Lemma 1.1 of http://www.math.wisc.edu/~passman/balgebra.pdf by Passman. I think he published this years later in Communications in Algebra.

Comment: Thanks!  He did indeed publish it; see http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2012.753604

Comment: I thought so but didn't have access.

Comment: This is very handy in semigroup theory. It leads to the quickest proof a finite semigroup has a faithful upper triangular representation iff its algebra does. I reproduced this period for my book on semigroup representations.